# Force maven to look for dependency in local repository

Tags: maven

I have 4 snapshot dependencies in my Pom and I want to force just 1 dependency to be looked always from local repository only. Is it possible to define in that dependency only that it should be fetched from local?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @ilikeorangutans Why do you ask why ?

Comment: @PavelNiedoba because knowing the reason may help provide a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure the process would change, not matter what the reason is. I assume you mean that if you know the reason you could then tell the OP about how wrong their approach is.

Comment: It is an interview question, maybe thats why he asking...

Comment: I was working on POC back then, didn't had a repository to push my code, so wanted to read it from local .m2 repo.

Answer (score 14):

force maven to run in offline mode by passing `-o` switch

Comment: He said he wants _one_ dependency to be fetched from local, not all of them.

Comment: Yes, I guess -o will force offline for all dependencies. I am looking for just 1 to be fetched offline.

Comment: what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: is it possible candidate for `system` scoped dependency ?

Comment: `system` isn't recommended per the gurus at [Sonatype](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html): "The system scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide an explicit path to the JAR on the local file system.  <..snip..> Note that this scope is not recommended (you should always try to reference dependencies in a public or custom Maven repository)."

Comment: @JigarJoshi The reason behind it is that I want to build the project locally and then pick its dependency from local. This project is used purely for testng testcases.

Comment: if you have it open in eclipse workspace you can choose enable workspace resolution, so it will first try to search project in eclipse workspace then it will go to download jar

Answer (score 3):

If there is a timestamped version of the dependency available you can use the versions-maven-plugin to [lock the snapshot](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/lock-snapshots-mojo.html) to that specific version.